# Can I write to files without assigning buffer

Tags: c, file

Is there a way to use `fwrite` or another file writing function without assigning the buffer to a variable?

Given the fact that my data is a simple constants `uint8_t` is there a better way than

```
const uint8_t a = 'A';
const uint8_t b = 'B';

if (cond)
   fwrite(&a, 1, 1, out_file);
else
   fwrite(&b, 1, 1, out_file);
```

EDIT: For single characters there exists `fputc` (didn't come up in my searches because I was looking for write). Is there any way to do it for multibyte data like ints?

I'm looking for ways to prevent having this sort of code

```
const uint16_t val1 = CONST_1;
const uint16_t val2 = CONST_2;
const uint16_t val3 = CONST_3;
const uint16_t val4 = CONST_4;
const uint16_t val5 = CONST_5;

if (cond1)      { fwrite(&val1, sizeof(val1), 1, out_file); }
else if (cond2) { fwrite(&val1, sizeof(val1), 1, out_file); }
// etc
```

Instead of simply

```
if (cond1)      { fputint(CONST_1, out_file); }
else if (cond2) { fputint(CONST_2, out_file); }
// etc
```

Comment: `fwrite()` is the primary mechanism if you're using file stream (`FILE *`) I/O.  If you drop down into Unix file descriptor (`int`) I/O there are more choices as to how to write data, but in the context, you'd end up doing something like `write(fd, &a, 1)` (where `fd` is the file descriptor).  So, there's not a lot of practical difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think we can say that `write` [for a _single_ byte] does a syscall [which introduces significant overhead] for _each_ byte written. By doing `fwrite`, the data is buffered internally by the stream, and the stream I/O will do far fewer syscalls (i.e. `write` calls). Thus, `fwrite` will be more efficient. If we have a larger buffer (e.g. `uint8_t buf[1024];`) and do (e.g.)  `write(fd,buf,sizeof(buf))` the overhead is reduced and may be faster

Comment: So there's no way to write to a file without having some sort of intermediate variable? something like fputint(int, FILE *) analogous to fputc(char, FILE *)

Comment: @CraigEstey: but the question asks for "without a buffer" in the title … :D … I agree, but then you're going against the question title.

Comment: No matter what stream primitives are used (e.g. `fputc`) or any other method, they will _all_ use `write(2)` eventually [using a buffer, under the hood]. As to your `fputint`, you could code one yourself, or use `int foo = 23; fwrite(&foo,sizeof(foo),1,out_file);` The `fputint` will pretty much do what the example I just gave does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Granted. But, the speed comparison holds [even more] for the single byte example.

Comment: @CraigEstey: speed isn't a criterion mentioned in the question.  Single character `write()` calls are not particularly efficient (but neither are they so inefficient that they're unusable — usually, subject to no silly options on the `open()` call, etc), but writing `A` or `B` to a file isn't likely to be really representative of the work load.  The file won't be very exciting to read — sort of sheep-like: BAA BAA BAABAABAAAABBBBAAAA.

Comment: Similar to `fputc`, there also exists `fputs` if you already have a string to write out.

Comment: @Craig I think writing my own function is probably the best alternative, I just want to avoid having a list of variables at the top like `const int a = CONST_1; const int b = CONST_2; const int c = CONST_3;` etc.

Comment: Yes, writing your own would [probably] be the best bet--custom tailored to your exact need(s). Partly because there _isn't_ something standard that exactly matches `fputint`. You're at liberty to create as many wrapper functions as you desire. To maintain abstractness, with `typedef int age_t; putage(age_t age,FILE *fi) { fputint(age); }` If you [ever] change `age_t` to (e.g.) `short`, you can do: `putage(age_t age,FILE *fi) { putint16(age,fi); }` in a single place and all the rest of the code remains unchanged.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. What do you mean by “without a buffer”? You can write any object to a stream with `fwrite(&object, sizeof object, 1, out_file);`. You do not need to put the object in a buffer before doing that, and passing it to some `fput` routine by value does not accomplish anything different. And what does `if (cond)` have to do with whether or not a buffer is used? What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: @Eric see my previous comment, what I meant was whether I could write to a file without _assigning_ a buffer. I have an `enum` and the value to write depends on the condition.

Comment: @Blake: The small objects you are writing are trivial. Simply do `const uint8_t x = cond ? a : b; fwrite(&x, sizeof x, 1, out_file);` and be done with it. You could even write this in one expression as `fwrite((uint8_t []) {cond ? a : b}, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, out_file);`.

Comment: The conditions I have are much less trivial, I really don't want to rewrite it with the conditional operator

Comment: @Blake: consider [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54032075/edit)ing your question again to explain more, give additional context and motivation. Avoid commenting your own question

Answer (score 1):

> Can I write to files without a buffer  (?)
>
> Given the fact that my data is a simple constants `uint8_t` is there a better way than ...?

Consider the 2 writes below.  In both cases `a` *is* the buffer. [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032075/can-i-write-to-files-without-a-buffer/54032671#comment94901130_54032075)

```
const uint8_t a = 'A';
fwrite(&a, 1, 1, out_file);
fputc(a, out_file);
```

It truly is amazing how good compilers can be these days.  Quite possible both lines of code could emit the same code.   Code for clarity and let the compiler handle what is really a micro-optimizing concern.

---

> Is there any way to do it for multibyte data like `int`s?

```
int i = rand();
fwrite(&i, sizeof i, 1, out_file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between values that exist during runtime, and ones that only exist during compilation.

Any value compiled into the data section of the program exists at an address during runtime, and for multi-byte values passing by reference is the norm (and the only practical choice for 64+ bit values). This also means that values that only exist during compile time, cannot be addressed directly, this is mostly macros (like enums). Enums are generally used statically during runtime, which means that they might never leave the program section, and become addressable.

However, you are allowed to reuse variables for your constants, here are two examples using raw posix/linux write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum {
    FIRST = 10000,
    SECOND,
    THIRD
};

//This can (and probably will automatically) be inlined
void write_constant(uint16_t val, int fd)
{
    write(fd, &val, sizeof(val));
}

int main (void)
{
    int fd;
    uint16_t out;
    fd = open("/tmp/testfile", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0640);

    //First example, reusing variable and assigning compile time constants:
    out = FIRST;  write(fd, &out, sizeof(out));
    out = SECOND; write(fd, &out, sizeof(out));
    out = THIRD;  write(fd, &out, sizeof(out));

    //Second example, wrapping the write in a function
    //This wraps the value inside an uint16_t value on either stack or register:
    write_constant(FIRST,fd);
    write_constant(SECOND,fd);
    write_constant(THIRD,fd);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

One thing to note when writing multiple integers directly without a formatter, is that the endianness from the program is preserved into the file, and they are mostly not human readable.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

```
if (cond)
   fwrite((uint8_t[]){'A'}, 1, 1, out_file);
else
   fwrite((uint8_t[]){'B'}, 1, 1, out_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use fwrite or another file writing function without assigning the buffer to a variable?

Of course, you could write a literal string, e.g.

```
fwrite("\1", 1, 1, file);
```

or

```
fwrite("\2\3\0\17", 4, 1, file);
```

In the later example, the string contains a <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte in third position.

Remember however that binary formats are in practice tied to some architecture (it won't be easy to read on some ARM a binary file written on x86 e.g. because these processors have different [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

Of course, you should care about [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) if that literal string is supposed to encode an integer in several bytes. Then using compound literals, as [answered by Kamil Cuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048098/841108), should be easier.

In practice, you might prefer [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) techniques (because binary formats like [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) are architecture-neutral) and in some cases you want [textual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) formats like [JSON](https://json.org/), [YAML](https://yaml.org/), etc.... (because they are easier to debug). You'll find libraries to help you.